# What are "relevant operations" in analysis of algorithms?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, analysis

I've been studying analysis of algorithms, and multiple times I've come across the idea that to define the time complexity of an algorithm I have to find the number of "relevant operations" performed by the algorithm. However, not a single source (Cormen, Skiena, Sedgewick...), at least to my knowledge, mentions HOW I can know what operations are in fact relevant. Any help?

Comment: Formally, you start with a [model of computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation) which is a list of primitive operations and their time costs, which is designed to be a good balance between 1. resembling a real physical computer and 2. being mathematically convenient. There's a tag full of questions about models of computation on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computation-models) where your question would fit in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you just count the operations, that you care about in your given context.

E.g.

```
fib(n)
{
   if(n < 2) 
      return 1;

   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}
```

The operations you can find in this code are:

- if statement
- comparison
- return a value
- recursive call
- addition

Every operation takes some time to be executed, but every operation is executed really fast (assuming the input `n` is a 64 bit number and the program runs on a "normal" computer). So the complexity of this function has to come from the recusive calls and especially not from the call it self, but from the number of calls. So you count the recursive calls and forget about the other operations, knowing that they run fast, means `O(1)` (constant time).

The reason why you can ignore some operations, is that you calculate the complexity in terms of `o`, `O`, `Θ`, `Ω` or `ω` ([Landau-Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)), which allows you to calculate in asymtotics, where slwo growing parts and constants doesn't play any role.

I think there is no easy answer how to know, what operations are relevant. There are easy examples (like the one I gave), but in general it is not that easy. Then you have to count everything that could be relevant until you notice, that it's not.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of suspected that. Either way, thanks a lot for your explanation, it helped solve a lot of other doubts!

Comment: @Ed_SR I think it becomes easier over time. After you have analyzed a lot of algorithms, you get theright view for this. You can find many examples here on Stackoverflow.